# Finding the inverse of Hadamard matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms

The $Hadamard\,\,matrices\,\,{H_0},\,\,{H_1},\,\,{H_2}, \ldots $ are defined as follows. Let
${H_0}$ be the $1 \times 1$ matrix $\left[ 1 \right]$. For $k = 1,2, \ldots ,$ let ${H_k}$ be the ${2^k} \times {2^k}$ matrix $${H_k} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{H_{k - 1}}}&{{H_{k - 1}}} \\ 
  {{H_{k - 1}}}&{ - {H_{k - 1}}} 
\end{array}} \right]$$

1. How to show that ${H_k}$ is invertible?
2. How to recover $x$ from ${H_k}x$ in $O(n\log n)$ time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Prove that $H_kH_k^T$ is a scalar matrix (induction on $k$). $H_k$ is actually symmetric, so :-)
2. [Fast Walsh-Hadamard Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform). A bit more of the theory [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform).